# Ionic 2 camera usage other than base64 encode

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view, ionic-popup

Is there any way to use the camera, but the picture not to be base64 encoded on ionic 2 platform? 
I want to use other encode than base64.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/camera/

Quote from the Ionic docs:

> Choose the format of the return value. Defined in
>   Camera.DestinationType. Default is FILE_URI. DATA_URL : 0, Return
>   image as base64-encoded string, FILE_URI : 1, Return image file URI,
>   NATIVE_URI : 2 Return image native URI (e.g., assets-library:// on iOS
>   or content:// on Android)

So you now have `Camera.DestinationType` to equal `DATA_URL`. If you don't want this you can use `FILE_URI` which will retrieve the file URI where after that you could use another cordova plugin to actually retrieve the image from the URI so that you can send it to your server

or

`NATIVE_URI` which will return `assets-library://.....` on iOS and `content://.....` on Android.

Which one you need will depend on your use case scenario.